# How to get more relevant results with mongoDB full text search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I created index for name field in my schema. 
Here is my code.

```
`Product.find( {$text : {$search : "apple macbook pro"} }, {score : { $meta: "textScore" }}).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" }}).exec((err,res)=>{

      console.log("res is  "+JSON.stringify(res));
 })`
```

My json response is

`[

      {

         "name":"Macbook Pro 13 and Pro Touch 13\" (2016, 2017) Case, Snugg Apple Macbook Pro 13 and Pro Touch 13\" (2016, 2017) Retina Cover [Deluxe Satin Touch] Ultra-Slim Shell Skin Design - Gold Marble",
      {

         "name":"ProCase 12 - 12.9 Inch Laptop Sleeve Case Cover Bag for Macbook Surface Pro 4 3, Apple iPad Pro, Most 11\" 12\" Laptop Ultrabook Notebook MacBook Chromebook -Grey"
      },
      {

         "name":"Macbook Pro Touch 15\" (2016, 2017) Case, Snugg Apple Macbook Pro Touch 15\" (2016, 2017) Retina Cover [Deluxe Satin Touch] Ultra-Slim Shell Skin Design - Gold Marble"
      },
      {

         "name":"MacBook Pro 15 Case 2017 & 2016 A1707, ProCase Rubberized Hard Case Shell Cover and Keyboard Cover for Apple Macbook Pro 15\" (Newest 2017 & 2016 Release) with Touch Bar and Touch ID -Black"
      },
      {

         "name":"Apple MacBook Pro MC118LL/A 15.4-Inch Laptop"
      },

  / *  I need to get this record at top  as gave key word as apple macbook pro  */ 
 ]`

I need to get the last record to be at top as I gave key word as "apple macbook pro"

Please help me fix this for getting better relevant results.

Comment: So what do the `"score"` results actually say? You omitted them from the data posted here and that's the important part. Are there actually other fields in the text index? Are there weights assigned to the index? These are the things we need to know in order to understand the result.

Comment: I only used indexing for name field. Can please mention how to get the score results.

Comment: They are actually present in your results. You have removed them when posting in this question.